# Usage of GCMS for business purposes

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'd like to use the GCMS for my app that will be used by companies. To make the server notify the users upon updates I thought about using the GCMS. While reading the Terms of Services I stumbled upon the part:

> d. API Limitations Google sets and enforces limits on your use of the
>   APIs (e.g. limiting the number of API requests that you may make or
>   the number of users you may serve), in our sole discretion. You agree
>   to, and will not attempt to circumvent, such limitations documented
>   with each API. If you would like to use any API beyond these limits,
>   you must obtain Google's express consent (and Google may decline such
>   request or condition acceptance on your agreement to additional terms
>   and/or charges for that use). To seek such approval, contact the
>   relevant Google API team for information (e.g. by using the Google
>   developers console).

What are these Limitations exactly and how much is this Google express consent?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit that you can normally hit unless you're trying to abuse the system somehow.

Comment: Still I'd like to know a number so I can sleep safe